# Merge single band and multi band color images

Tags: raster, aerial-photography

I have two color images (orthophotomaps). One is only 1-band with color map and second is with 3-bands.

How can I merge them with any FOSS tools or ArcGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for answering to myself. In case, if someone wonder how to mosaic color map image (1 band) with RGB image (3 bands). I figured, that simplest method will be to convert color map into RGB (possible in Arc with Copy Raster tool) and then mosaic them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at using the [Composite Bands](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Composite_Bands/00170000009p000000/) tool in arctoolbox?

Comment: Composite Bands will composite bands in deed. However I need to mosaic two images, one with color map and second in RGB. I think the only way to do it is either convert color map into RGB or other way around.