# How to produce a mean raster file based on other raster files?

Tags: raster, gdal, map-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools to flatten the jp2 to a single band (average the bands)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38948/tools-to-flatten-the-jp2-to-a-single-band-average-the-bands)

I have a number of raster files from a same area, that coordinates of corresponding pixels perfectly match one another. I have to perform simple operations like producing a raster that its pixel values are the average of a 3 raster files corresponding pixel values. Simply speaking, I want a new raster file that is average of 3 other raster files.

Comment: Search our site on "+raster +average" to find several duplicates of this question, each with good answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `gdal_calc.py`. You'll probably find some useful examples [here](http://smathermather.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/gdal_calc-py-raster-calculator-using-numby-functions/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a GUI use the [QGIS Raster Calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html). Though the documentation is sparse, it should be really easy for you to figure out how to use it to calculate the average of multiple rasters.